# Apache Wave API

Tags: java, web, api, google, apache

I'd like to create an application based around Apache Wave. Where can I learn more about working with Apache Wave and/or the API for a locally running instance?

At the moment, the extent of what I can find seems to be APIs for *Google Wave* (running off Google's servers) and that it's written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its still a work in progress. You should join the mailing list, which will get you in touch with what is going on, even if it includes implementation you dont care about. http://incubator.apache.org/wave/mailing-lists.html

Also these if you haven't seen.

http://googlewavedev.blogspot.com/
http://incubator.apache.org/wave/